# How do I turn off some formats in GeoServer's WMS?

Tags: geoserver, wms

I have published a couple of layers on my Geoserver.

To be complaint with the T&C of my data provider, I need to block the access of some of those layers as Vector data. Hence I have already blocked the WFS services on these Layers.

I came to know that even on the WMS service, you can get Vector Data, if you use GeoRSS and some of the [other formats](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/outputformats.html).

How do I block GeoRSS, SVG & UTFGrid as formats in the WMS Service?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the generic `Web Map Service` configuration (that is before you have chosen a workspace), you get options (at the bottom of the page) to configure the **Allowed MIME types for a GetMap request**, and also **Allowed MIME types for a GetFeatureInfo request**.

[image: Changing MIME types in GeoServer WMS]